# Escape key is not working in Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am Using Selenium WebDriver framework. I have a scenario where a button gets clicked after the textbox get populated and onblur of the textbox.

Below is the code which I used for escape sequence which enable the button after filling in textbox.The button get enabled only when the textbox gets filled and when the focus moves out of textbox.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://localhost:8081/TestAutomation/Escape.jsp");
driver.manage().window().maximize();

WebElement txtBxHandle = driver.findElement(By.name("txtName"));        
txtBxHandle.sendKeys("Socrates");

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);

WebElement BnEnable = driver.findElement(By.name("btnSubmit"));
BnEnable.click();
```

The above code is not working.I tried keyPressNative but in vain.

Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 13):

Based on my experience with the Python bindings, you'd have to call `.perform()` on your action chain. I see the Java bindings have the [same method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#perform%28%29). So:

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform();
```

Answer (score 12):

I have 3 concepts to do this.

1) You can focus on Submit button to lose focus from text box by using JS with Selenium WebDriver. The code is as below:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByName('btnSubmit')[0].focus();");
```

2) You can use Actions class as below:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();
```

3) You can try the following also:

```
txtBxHandle.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

Comment: For me in C# second option works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);
```

Comment: Could you better explain your solution?

Comment: Yes, You can use Java Robot class from java.awt package

Comment: This requires the browser window to be focused. This probably doesn't work in headless mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following snippet to escape without finding/defining any element on web page

```
WebElement currentElement = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
currentElement().sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

If you are using Serenity and willing to ESCAPE then use following snippet

```
withAction().sendKeys(Keys.TAB).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

to

```
txtBxHandle.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE);
```

Comment: While Implementing the code in to my customized framework I read from excel sheet the input values.So I don't have reference to previous object

Answer (score 0):

try this

`SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");`

Answer (score -1):

escape in action class send keys and escape in robot class does not work for me in chrome too.
try any way if close element is given or use movebyoffset

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29879328)

Comment: My apologies for helping moderate your response, @sagarp. My comment aims to point out your reply didn't seem suitable for the occasion. If that's incorrect, then it would be more helpful to describe why I was mistaken. Or otherwise, you could update your reply to better suit the question posed. I meant no harm at all and was simply trying to help out the community. Hence, I would expect kind correspondence as befits the regular code of conduct on StackOverflow.

Comment: By the way, I anticipated your response to not answer the question, as it seems you're talking along the lines of "I am experiencing the same issue." Clearer use of punctuation and capitalization could help a long way for others to understand your intent.